# Template Strings Without Variable Interpolation

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, interpolation, template-strings

Is it possible to have a template string in JavaScript that does not interpolate the variable values?  I would like to have actual JS code blocks (which will be multi-line and contain escape sequences) like this example:

```
...

return String.raw`console.log(\`Here is my code:\n\n ${code}\`);`
```

that I can pass between functions in my Node.js app.  I have no problem escaping backticks but I'd like to know if there's an easy way to stop interpolation of the variables so that I can have template strings nested inside of my template string.

I know that one option is to define code as `let code = '${code}';` but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it where interpolation was completely turned off in the same way that `String.raw` turns off interpretation of escape sequences.

Comment: Could be an XY problem. I'd also look at the reason why you need to do this in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't TLs interpolate when `${...}` is encountered? Your templates are `{{}}`? Aren't they different from each other?

Comment: It could be an XY problem.  I'm looking for something similar to PHP's nowdoc construct for Node.  The main reason I want to do it via nesting TSs is because template strings seem like the most convenient way to handle multi-line strings of code that I want dynamic values in.  The problem is that when they are nested I need a way to prevent the nested TS from being parsed.